# Are there English translations of Upanishad bhAshyas from dvaita and vishishtha advaita perspectives?

Tags: upanishads, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

Sri Madhva wrote commentaries on upanishads from dvaita perspective.

Sri Ranga Ramanuja wrote commentaries on upanishads from vishishtha advaita perspective.

Are these commentaries available in English translations? If yes, where can they be obtained?

Comment: http://ebooks.tirumala.org and http://vishnudut1926.blogspot.com/?m=1 you will find some of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Dvaita*** commentaries are available at [Nagesh Sonde's website](http://www.nageshsonde.com/)

**Sri Madhvacharya's Bhasya on Upanishads:**

- [Isha Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Sri_Madhva's%20_Bhashya_on_Isha_panishad_book.pdf)
- [Chhandogya Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/chhandogya-upanishad.pdf)
- [Katha Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Katha%20_Upanishad_book.pdf)
- [Kena Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Bhashya_on_Kena_Upanishad.pdf)
- [Mandukya Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Sri_Madhva_Mandukya_Upanishad.pdf)
- [Mundaka Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/download.gif)
- [Brihadaranyaka Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/brihad-aranyak-upanishad-commentary.pdf)
- [Taittariya Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Sri-Madhvachachaarya-Bhashya-On-Taittiriya-Upanishad.pdf)
- [Prashna Upanishad](http://www.nageshsonde.com/images/Prashnopanishad.pdf)

---

It is difficult to find and get English translation of Ranga Ramanujacharya's (or ***Vishishtadvaita***) commentary on Upanishads online.  As said in comment, you may try http://ebooks.tirumala.org/ for finding books e.g.
[**Isavasyopanishad** Bhashya by Vedanta Desikan](http://ebooks.tirumala.org/Home/Download/?ID=1796);

Or you can purchase some useful books of them from Exotic India:

- [**Shwetashvatara Upanishad** with Commentary of Ranga Ramanuja](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/shwetashvatara-upanishad-with-commentary-of-ranga-ramanuja-critical-edition-NZF935/)
- [**Aitareya Upanishad** with Four Commentaries According to Ramanuja School](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/aitareya-upanishad-with-four-commentaries-according-to-ramanuja-school-NZF642/)
- [**Mandukya Upanishad** with Five Commentaries of The Ramanuja School](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/mandukya-upanishad-with-five-commentaries-of-ramanuja-school-NZA977/)
- [**Brihadaranyakopanishat**: With Ramanuja's commentary](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/brhadaranyakopanisat-with-rangaramanuja-s-commentary-volume-i-NAH283/)
- [**Chandogya Upanishad** with Four Commentaries According to Ramanuja School](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/chandogya-upanishad-with-four-commentaries-according-to-ramanuja-school-set-of-2-volumes-NZC466/)
- [**Mundaka Upanishad** with Four Commentaries According to Ramanuja School](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/mundaka-upanishad-with-four-commentaries-according-to-ramanuja-school-NZE715/)

Apart from these, One very useful book [**Five Principal Upanishads**- Ishavasya, Kena, Katha, Taittiriya and Mundaka Upanishads (With Sanskrit Text, Transliteration, Translation and Exhaustive Commentary **Based on Ramanuja School**)](https://www.exoticindia.com/book/details/five-principal-upanishads-exhaustive-commentary-in-english-on-ishavasya-kena-katha-taittiriya-mundaka-upanishads-with-original-sanskrit-transliteration-translation-exposition-and-annotations-based-on-ramanuja-school-IHG016/) is also available!

Comment: Link for Mundaka Upanishad is not working. Please fix the link.